# How to run android emulator with the system image generated from newly built android lollipop code?

Tags: android, emulation

I have downloaded android lollipop source code. I have built it successfully. The system img is generated. How do I run this on an emulator? I want to check if this is working. And i dont want to use the default system images . Please guide.

Regards,
Sathya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enter you build root folder.

1.source

```
    source build/envsetup.sh
```

2.lunch, select the device you built. for example arm-full:

```
    lunch 1
```

3.launch emulator

```
    emulator
```

then the emulator should start with the systemimg you built

you can add options to the "emulator" cmd, run "emulator --help" for details

Comment: Is there a need to do mksdcard??

Comment: if you don't need to install apps that require an external sdcard, then normally it's not neccessary to make a sdcard img. if you need to push files to system partition, be sure to increase the partition size. @Sathya

Comment: Oh okay.Thank you. And How can i run a system image which is built in a different system on the emulator present in my system? @wrkwrk

Comment: how can i place my built system image in the sdk/system-image/android-21/default/ so that i can run it from there? Please help me out on this.